# Does a subclass NEED to have a constructor?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I've been learning about inheritance and I was just curious. I know that the subclass will automatically call the superclass's constructor even if you don't use the `super()` operator, so I wanted to know if it is even necessary for a subclass to have a constructor in it.

Comment: well.. if you don't provide one, the compiler will do it for you. So, yes "IT IS NECESSARY to have a constructor". It's just not necessary that you should "define  it".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A subclass needs a constructor if the superclass does not have a default constructor (or has one that is not accessible to the subclass). If the subclass has no constructor at all, the compiler will automatically create a `public` constructor that simply calls through to the default constructor of the superclass.

Regarding calling `super()`: the first thing every constructor must do is either call a different constructor in the same class by calling `this()` (possibly with some arguments) or call a constructor of its superclass by calling `super()` (again, possibly with arguments). Neither of those calls can go anywhere else. If a constructor doesn't start with either one, the compiler will automatically insert a call to `super()` (without any arguments). So if the behavior you want is to call through to the default superclass constructor (and, many times, it is) then you don't need to explicitly call `super()` yourself.

There's also one situation where you do not need to provide a constructor (in fact, you can't provide one) even when the superclass has no default constructor. This case (described in [section 15.9.5.1 of the Java Language Sepcification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5.1)) is when you create an anonymous subclass of a class using a non-default constructor; the compiler will automatically create a constructor with the correct arguments and call up to the corresponding (non-default) superclass constructor. For instance:

```
class X {
    public X(int value) { ... } // no default constructor!
    public void foo() { ... }
}

X myX = new X(3) {
    @Override
    public void foo() { ... }
};
```

Then `myX` will be an instance of an anonymous subclass of X with a compiler-generated constructor that takes an `int` argument and calls `super(intArg)`.

Because you *cannot* write a constructor for anonymous classes, there's an issue: what if you need to do some object initialization when the object is created? The solution is to use an [instance initializer block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). For example:

```
X myX = new X(3) {
    // Field unique to this subclass of X:
    private int baz;
    {
        // code here runs as if it were at the start of every constructor
        baz = ...;
    }
    @Override
    public void foo() { ... }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

If the super class does not have a default (ie no args) constructor, then you *must* define a constructor that calls a specific super constructor.

If the super class *does* have a default constructor, you don't have to declare a constructor, because the following constructor will be *implicitly* defined for you if you don't declare any constructors:

```
SubClass() {
    super();  // Note: the no-args super constructor may itself be implicit
}
```

So in that case, you don't have to declare a constructor in the sub class.

Answer (score 2):

If the default superclass constructor accessed through super() is available, then the subclass does not need to have an explicit constructor; it will automatically get a default no argument constructor.  If the superclass has explicit constructors all of which take arguments, then the subclass needs an explicit constructor as well, since without such a constructor there would be no way to know what arguments the superclass constructor should be called with.

Answer (score 0):

If default constructor is available in super class then compiler will include default constructor invocation in sub class's default constructor. For Example -

```
class  Base(){
  Base(){ // default constructor
    ...
  }
}

class Sub extends Base{
   // no constructor
}
```

In this case not required.

```
class  Base(){
  Base( int i){ // no default constructor
    ...
  }
}

class Sub extends Base{
   // no constructor
}
```

In this case it required.

```
class Sub extends Base{
   Sub(){ 
      Base(1);
   }
}
```