# Spring/DI: Constructor injection in child class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I've got a parent class with a constructor injected dependency:

```
class ParentClass {
  private final MyService service;

  @Autowired
  ParentClass(MyService service) {
    this.service=service;
  }
  // ...
}
```

If I inherit from this class, do I always need to redefine a constructor calling the parent constructor?

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  // Do I really need this?
  @Autowired
  ChildClass(MyService service) {
    super(service);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Using setter injection, I seem to be able to keep the dependency in the parent class and do not need to rewire it in the child, which sounds good to me if the child class does not touch the functionality linked to the dependency:

```
class ParentClass {
  private MyService service;

  @Autowired
  void setMyService(MyService service) {
    this.service=service;
  }
  // ...
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  // ...
}
```

It seems that if I want to avoid repeating the autowiring code and handling the dependency in the child, I can only do this using setter or field injection.

Is there a cleaner pattern to do this dependency injection or is this a case where field/setter injection has to be used, even though constructor injection is recommended?

Thanks!

Comment: In plain java also if you have a parent class with non-default constructor (no-arguments constructor), in your child class you have to redefine a constructor which calls the non-default parent constructor. So it is java related your question about the constructors, Spring/DI has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks. My question was concerning the DI problem. I edited it for clarity.

Comment: at the moment you're also asking "If I inherit from this class, do I always need to redefine a constructor calling the parent constructor?". Maybe you should edit your question, because at the moment the answer is yes, you have to, and it has nothing to do with DI

Comment: updated my answer, please take a look

Answer (score 7):

It's not a Spring issue, it's Java. Try removing child class constructor, and see what happens for yourself - your code shouldn't compile. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470316/does-a-subclass-need-to-have-a-constructor) answer, it was described before.

Answering your question on dependency injection, yes, `@Autowired` works for setter in the parent class, but as long as you don't override it in the subclass (give it a try). The reason is that Spring deals with objects, not classes, so when a subclass is instantiated Spring is not checking annotations on overridden methods in the parent class, unless annotation is marked as [@Inherited](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) (`@Autowired` is not).

So, you would either have to use `@Autowired` for each subclass (which I don't see as a big problem, actually), switch to setter injection, replace subclassing with delegation, or make parent class abstract and use constructor injection only in subclasses.